# Class Reference Shortcut

Tags: c#, class

I currently have two solutions inside my project. 
Solution 1 is the GameEngine
Solution 2 is essentially the front end Adventure

In order to access classes from the GameEngine library a Singleton design approach is used, so for me to access my inventory class for example GameEngine.Instance.Inventory is used.

However, this is adding quite a lot of code now, doing GameEngine.Instance each time, is there a way I can invoke a method or return so I can simply refer to Inventory and it will return the GameEngine.Instance.Inventory class instead? Basically a shortcut.

Thanks In advance :)

Comment: @AD.Net: No, that won't do it. `using` aliases are fine for *types*, but this is an *expression*, with two property getters.

Comment: got it, did not understand it before.

Comment: You can also alias a type with `using ge = ApexCorp.Games.GameEngine;` and then use it as `ge.Inventory` where `Inventory` is a static property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also add a static method so it will be accessible through the entire project

```
public static ClsInventory GetInventory()
{
   return GameEngine.Instance.Inventory;
}
```

Comment: You can (and should) also have static property. ;)

Answer (score 4):

One way is to set up a property:

```
public GameEngine.Inventory Inventory
{
    get { return GameEngine.Instance.Inventory; }
}
```

Now you can use `Inventory` all over the class to refer to your singleton object. However this will work only within a particular class.

Also, as per @Leri's comment, this migth (and might not) affect performance.

Comment: That adds additional method call, which kinda drops performance and is noticeable in games.

Comment: @Leri: the compiler would likely inline such a property; it's not likely to cause any noticeable effect.

Comment: Tried this, Keep getting error An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Adventure.Actions.PlayerItemInventory.get

Comment: @Kehza, well, this depends on how you are calling this property. You might need to declare it static

Comment: @Leri `Instance` and `Inventory` are also two lookups that could be one. Either way, for performance-critical cases we could copy the reference to a local variable first.

Answer (score 3):

Use a static property:

```
private static GameEngine.Inventory _inventory;
public static GameEngine.Inventory Inventory
{
  get { 
    if (_inventory == null) {
       _inventory = GameEngine.Instance.Inventory;
     } 

     return _inventory;
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that by caching the value you are assuming that the `GameEngine.Inventory` field never changes... and if that is the case, then this could easily just be a one-line static field: `public static readonly GameEngine.Inventory Inventory = GameEngine.Instance.Inventory;`

Answer (score 1):

If your singleton instance is never changed, you can safely use a variable for the instance:

```
var i = GameEngine.Instance;
```

then use it with:

```
i.Inventory
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to augment the answers.They all respond properly your question and I upvoted all. However,  I would recomend instead of using a singleton, try to change your aproach to injection of dependencies to acces "global" instances.

What would happend when you want to acces other (global) object rather than the inventory? You will have to add another property to your GameEngine. Your engine will become a Frankestain with so many properties belongin to game engine internal instances. This violates the single responsablity pattern.

Besides, when you want to unit test your game, you wil have to setup the ENTIRE GameEngine for each test / fixture. IOD also helps you to decouple your code.

Comment: Although IoC is generally good design practice, using it for a game engine is likely to have an unnecessary performance hit.

Comment: Depends on where you use it. In the given example the player press a button and the inventory appears. How many ms are lost in IoC? Does it matters since is not being used in the render engine?

Comment: Without knowing the full game architecture, it's hard to accurately say, my comment was intended as more of a footnote than a criticism.